# Log file size or age

Tags: authentication, log, logging, logs

I'd like to change various log files (particularly auth.log) to retain info for anywhere from the last 30-90 days.  Right now it only has about 4 days worth of info.  How do I modify these settings via the GUI or command prompt?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu uses logrotate

You configure it in `/etc/logrotate.d`

Sample syntax:

```
   /var/log/messages {
       rotate 5
       weekly
       postrotate
           /usr/bin/killall -HUP syslogd
       endscript
   }
```

for full configuration options see:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/logrotate.8.html

http://articles.slicehost.com/2010/6/30/understanding-logrotate-on-ubuntu-part-1

http://articles.slicehost.com/2010/6/30/understanding-logrotate-on-ubuntu-part-2