# How can I keep more auth.log files?

Tags: log

I'd like to keep more than the default 5 log files at /var/log/auth.log.  What do I need to change to keep x number of them?

Comment: By looking in `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate`, I found `/etc/logrotate.conf`. There's a `rotate` parameter in there.  Is that the one?

Comment: Well, the answer was added after my comment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is done by `logrotate`, which as a daily `cron` job checks it's configuration files for log files that need rotating, compressing,  removal, and takes the necessary action(s).

For `/var/log/auth.log`, which is actually a `rsyslog` managed file, as `rsyslog` dumps all authentication info (`auth`, `authpriv` facilities) in there (conf file: `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`), the relevant configuration file for `logrotate` is `/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog`.

On my 14.04 that contains:

```
/var/log/mail.info
/var/log/mail.warn
/var/log/mail.err
/var/log/mail.log
/var/log/daemon.log
/var/log/kern.log
/var/log/auth.log
/var/log/user.log
/var/log/lpr.log
/var/log/cron.log
/var/log/debug
/var/log/messages
{
        rotate 4
        weekly
        missingok
        notifempty
        compress
        delaycompress
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                reload rsyslog >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
        endscript
}
```

So `/var/log/auth.log` is being rotated by this configuration.

To modify the behavior to keep desired number of rotated files, you can either change `rotate` parameter to your desired value (any positive integer, `0` will remove the old files instantly) in the `{ ... }` section following the filename declaration, but this will change the behavior for all mentioned files, which might not be the desired behavior.

Instead, remove `/var/log/auth.log` from there, and make a separate entry for this by putting the following at the end:

```
/var/log/auth.log
{
        rotate 10
        weekly
        missingok
        notifempty
        compress
        delaycompress
        postrotate
                reload rsyslog >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
        endscript
}
```

The above will rotate `/var/log/auth.log`, `weekly`, with `compress`-ion, not if it's empty (`notifempty`), and will keep `10` rotated copies, and the older ones that that will be removed.

Change these to meet your need, and also read `man 5 logrotate.conf`.

Comment: Cool. Thanks very much.  That's a better answer than is here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/252583/log-file-size-or-age

Comment: Too fast for me....

Comment: @ElderGeek Haha, the grass is always greener on the other side, huh? I always thought i'm the _slowest_ ;)

Comment: :-) Your approach is likely more technically correct.  I just looked and applied logic.

Answer (score 0):

Rotation schedules are defined in `/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog`

If we examine the file we can see that auth.log is one of the files that are configured to a rotate 4, weekly schedule by default. Notice that syslog conversely is set to rotate 7, daily schedule. You can follow the format for syslog and create an entry that follows the same format that will give you the results you want I.E. rotate X and the schedule desired as in daily, weekly or whatever. Pay attention to the the postrotate directive as well as it specifies the action that happens after the whole log rotation has completed.

```
/var/log/syslog
{
    rotate 7
    daily
    missingok
    notifempty
    delaycompress
    compress
    postrotate
        reload rsyslog >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
    endscript
}

/var/log/mail.info
/var/log/mail.warn
/var/log/mail.err
/var/log/mail.log
/var/log/daemon.log
/var/log/kern.log
/var/log/auth.log
/var/log/user.log
/var/log/lpr.log
/var/log/cron.log
/var/log/debug
/var/log/messages
{
    rotate 4
    weekly
    missingok
    notifempty
    compress
    delaycompress
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        reload rsyslog >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
    endscript
}
```

sources:

`man logrotate`

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-view-and-configure-linux-logs-on-ubuntu-and-centos